# Как сделать защищённый запрос к базе данных в 1c bitrix

Tags: sql, битрикс, запрос, 1с

Я новичок в 1c bitrix, есть такая проблема, надо вставить в базу данные от пользователя, как защититься от sql инъекций? Может в 1c bitrix есть подготовленные запросы, что-то похожее или альтернатива? Заранее спасибо.

```
$connection->queryExecute("UPDATE table SET option = new_value WHERE id = 1");
```

Comment: [Класс CDatabase](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cdatabase/index.php)

Comment: можете дать пример?

Comment: как это сделать для insert и update, я по докам не совсем понял.